# How do I include elements in xsl for optional tags in xml

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the xml I have.

```
   <Parent>
      <child>
         <child1>Ram</Child1>
         <child2>Buss</Child2>
      </child>
   </Parent>
```

For this xml I need to have and xsl file so as to generate the name of child 1 and child 2. But child 2 tags is optional. So I need to get the text content of child2 only if the  tag appears and also I have to give a slash character (/) between the text content of child1 and child2 if child2 tag appears. How do I do this in XSL?

Comment: So, do you want to produce: "Child1/Child2" or "Ram/Buss" ? In this question you seem to ask for both of these ...

Answer (score 1):

**This is probably one of the simplest and shortest solutions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="child2">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', .)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided  (text, corrected to be made) XML document**:

```
<Parent>
    <child>
        <child1>Ram</child1>
        <child2>Buss</child2>
    </child>
</Parent>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Ram/Buss
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<Parent>
    <child>
        <child1>Ram</child1>
    </child>
</Parent>
```

**again the wanted result is produced**:

```
Ram
```